# How do I trigger functionality in another plugin from my plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I need to write a WP plugin that will need to generate some QR code and to allow for file uploading/downloading, and to do other things based on the results of the QR code generation and file uploading/downloading. I know that there are existing plugins for both of these and I don't want to re-write them myself to not re-invent the wheel.

My ideal scenario is that I can tell people to install my plugin which will auto install the 2 plugins I'm dependent on. And then when they activate my plugin, it activates the other 2 plugins also.

In my plugin, I do work xyz1, and then when it comes to the file upload portion, I call something to trigger the file upload UI of plugin 1 to show, after it's done, I want to get results of its process and continue with my work for xyz2. I want the same thing for the QR code (plugin 2).

So, my questions are:

1. How do I make my plugin dependent on other plugins?
2. How do I show the UI of another plugin in my plugin and be able to use the results?
3. Can you show me code sample/sample plugins that does this?

Basically, anything that will lead me on the right path, or a detailed path, to achieving the ideal scenario above would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use TGM plugin activation - http://tgmpluginactivation.com/
2. Depends on the plugin, but for my requirement, I was able to find plugin WordPress file upload and use `do_shortcode()`. The downside of doing this is my plugin really doesn't "know" any success/failure status that happens inside of the other plugin (luckily, the plugin's creator have a redirect for success states, and that is sufficient for me to work with).

   - There are many libraries available also, and one can use composer to include those libraries to not re-invent the wheel. I've found that this speeds up development tremendously. The place to find those libraries are through a search engine, or through https://packagist.org/
3. Didn't find a sample plugin but I was able to successfully finish my plugin in less than 40 hours.

   ```
   echo do_shortcode('[wordpress_file_upload uploadpath="'.$relative_upload_path.'" 
   uploadpatterns="'.$allowedFileTypes.'" maxsize="2248" createpath="true" forcefilename="true"  
   redirect="true" redirectlink="'.$redirectlink.'" 
   notify="true" notifymessage="Image file was uploaded."]');
   ```